# Origen de la palabra "jariguay"

Tags: etimología, historia, comida, palabras-raras

La palabra **jariguay** no aparece en la edición actual del Diccionario de la lengua, ni en ninguno de los diccionarios que se pueden consultar mediante el NTLLE, en el Diccionario de americanismos, el CORDE o el CREA.

En el Fichero General de la RAE solo hay una ficha para [**jariguay**](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/PUNTOS_ROJOS/J_pdf/caja_002-1%20J%20PUNTO/00000086.pdf):

> **1. Refresco de mala calidad que se hacía antiguamente: "Bébete un jariguay". También *jeriguay.**
>   2. También vermut de baja calidad vendido a granel. Ver  *chismorrito.

y otra sobre [**jeriguay**](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/PUNTOS_ROJOS/J_pdf/caja_002-1%20J%20PUNTO/00001317.pdf), que proporciona información adicional:

> Refresco de naranja o de limón de baja calidad, hecho artesanalmente, parecido a la gaseosa. También se dice *jariguay.

La [Hemeroteca Digital](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/index.vm) apenas proporciona 18 resultados, todos en obras de acceso restringido, correspondientes a los años **1992 - 2017**.

En internet se encuentran algunas páginas en las que se menciona y describe, siempre de un modo muy similar, como en https://elpobrecitohabladordelsigloxxi.blogspot.com/2014/04/jariguay.html, en [Los orígenes del jariguay y uno bien fresco de atún con remolacha y fresas.](https://www.facebook.com/elcomidista/posts/511747915571742), en  [tuBabel.com](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/43637-jariguay) o en [Yo fui a EGB](https://ar-ar.facebook.com/yofuiaegb/posts/586571928020173):

> **jariguay**. Refresco barato, con sabor generalmente a naranja, aunque también había jariguay de cola y de limón. Las dosis de jariguay se servían generalmente en el mismo vaso, que no se lavaba entre toma y toma.

[WordMagicSoft](http://www.wordmagicsoft.com/dictionary/es-en/jariguay.php) incluso aporta la traducción al inglés:

> Translate "jariguay" to English: **cheap refreshment notoriously inferior to the regular one.**

Todos estos datos parecen avalar que se trata(ba) de un refresco barato, de mala calidad, de elaboración posiblemente casera o artesanal, que se consumía en los años setenta a noventa.

Sin embargo, no he encontrado en ninguna parte una mención, siquiera de pasada, a la etimología de la palabra ni a dónde se consumía (y si se sigue consumiendo).

Answer (score 4):

He encontrado varias interesantes referencias

Primero, [este comentario](https://www.tubabel.com/definicion/43637-jariguay) sobre la palabra describe la palabra como tal:

> Esta curiosa palabra "**jariguay**", de nombre a pais sudamericano (si se me permite la licencia), desde hace algunos años que no se suele oir, aunque a alguno aún se le escapa todavía para referirse a un brebaje de extraño gusto e igual procedencia.
>
> Se vendían a botellas de 1 litro y de varios gustos aunque de naranja sobre todo. Digo 'de gusto' por decir algo ... porque 'de sabor' era realmente malo. Incluso 'de color' era sospechoso : una especie de 'agua churri' de leve presencia anaranjada ... que no indicaba nada bueno ...
>
> Si no se quería gastar dinerillo, era una opción ... aunque lo mejor era decantarse por una bebida 'más consolidada'.
>
> Ejemplos : 
>   - Que malo el "jariguay" de naranja. Puaggg !. 
>   - He preparado un "jariguay" de limón : le he metido de todo ... así sabe ... 
>   - Este "jariguay" no hay quien se lo beba, aggg !.

Luego encontré en este diccionario que la [palabra viene de España](https://jergozo.com/significado/jariguay)

> Refresco barato con sabor notoriamente inferior al normal
>   País: **españa**

Para mí, más evidencia se encuentra en este blog que tiene referencias de tomar un ["jariguay" en Vadocondes Burgos](https://manuelsevillanobueno.jimdo.com/2014/07/27/del-jariguay-del-bomba/)

> De niño pasaba parte del verano en un pueblo de Burgos, Vadocondes. Antes de comer, la chavalada, íbamos al bar del Bomba a beber un “**Jariguay**”. El brebaje consistía en mezclar a pulso, gaseosa La Pitusa de limón, naranja y cola.

Finalmente, en Wikipedia, se encuentra [una página refiriendo a Vadocondes como](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vadocondes)

> una localidad y un municipio​ situados en la provincia de Burgos, comunidad autónoma de Castilla y León (España), comarca de La Ribera, partido judicial de Aranda, ayuntamiento del mismo nombre.

Por saber de seguro que no refiere a un Burgos fuera de España...

Answer (score -1):

Voy a contar creo que la verdadera historia de la palabra jariguay: por el año 1959 mas menos, en un bar que había en Bilbao en la calle Matico (BAR ROBLES) solía frecuentar el mismo un tal Paquirri, entrenador de futbol entre otros equipos el Iturrigorri y el Moraza, y tenia la costumbre de decir frases graciosas por ejemplo decía que en Agosto mucho frio en somorrostro, y le daba por pedir en aquel pequeño Bar de Bilbao dame un oribay, que debía estar relacionado con alguna bebida que habia en la Cervecera del Norte, aquí en Bilbao, y entonces un día un tal Parrala y su cuadrilla les dio por decir al dueño del Bar ( al oír lo de oribay) Oye danos un Jariguay que era un refresco principalmente de Naranja, luego vino también de limon, de piña, y hasta de menta,(hubo hasta una cancion Duo Rovi que la cantaba) etc, se llegó a cantar en Paris En Motmatre, años 1961.

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. No se debe publicar datos personales en preguntas y respuestas. Tus datos de contacto los puedes indicar en tu perfil de usuario. Todo esto se explica en el [help]. Con respecto como escribir una buena respuesta, quizás quieras ir directo a [answer] pero yo te recomendaría empezar por el [tour].